# Scaffolding Template Location of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, scaffolding

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Version. But not found where the location of scaffolding template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates for the Professional version of Visual Studio 2017 are located here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates

Answer (score 0):

If you Create your project by asp.net web application mvc then you can search your desire scaffolding template :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scaffolding Template Location for community version is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates\MvcView